# Native base checkbox shows hyphen instead of tick

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I am using Native Base with React Navigation 5, the checkbox of native base shows hyphen (-) instead of a tick. Also the Content is not displaying text.

[image]

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
// import NavigationInitializer from './route/NavigationSetup';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import { Root, Container, CheckBox, Content, Header, Text, Footer, Body } from 'native-base';
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); // remove unnecessary warnings
//  This is useful when there's a noisy warning that cannot be fixed, like those in a third-party dependency.

// AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => NavigationInitializer);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => () =>
    <Container>
        <Header>
            <Body>
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                    Checkbox
                </Text>
                <CheckBox checked={true} />
            </Body>
        </Header>
        <Content style={{ backgroundColor: "purple" }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>
                This is Content Section
            </Text>
        </Content>
        <Footer>
            <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>
                This is Footer Section
            </Text>
        </Footer>
    </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it by manual linking:

**react-native link react-native-vector-icons**

As discussed here:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2855

Answer (score 1):

There are two thigns you need to do. One, ensure you install react-native-vector-icons. Two, you need to add your fonts into the /android/app/build.gradle file. The following line will suffice.

//Fonts
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

This line loads all of your fonts in the react-native-vector-icons suite.

Comment: I updated gradle file. 
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Also, I could not find file fonts.gradle in that path in folder view.

Answer (score 0):

1- Edit android/app/build.gradle and add the following:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle";
```

2- Edit android/settings.gradle to look like this (without the +):

```
rootProject.name = 'MyApp'

include ':app'

+ include ':react-native-vector-icons'
+ project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

3- Edit android/app/build.gradle (note: app folder) to look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
  compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
+ compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}
```

4- copying all fonts from ../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts to ../android/app/src/main/assets/fonts